# Gradle error Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build a project but it keeps giving me this gradle error
I have upgraded my gradle 3.3 and my android plugin version to 2.3.3 but it's still giving me error
Any help would be appreciated
Error:

Error:(40, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'
Possible causes:

The project 'sms-mining-android' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project

The project 'sms-mining-android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Event Log:
Gradle sync failed: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-5'
ext.support_lib_version = '25.3.1'
ext.junit_version = '4.12'
ext.constraint_layout_version = '1.0.2'
ext.rxjava_version = '1.1.3'
ext.rxandroid_version = '1.1.0'
ext.mpchart_version='v3.0.2'
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
 #Mon Jun 19 10:49:52 IST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Comment: check Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2

Comment: I did, couldn't make anything of it

Comment: upload your app .gradle file

Answer (score 0):

try this gradle configuration ,it works for me :

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-5'
ext.support_lib_version = '25.3.1'
ext.junit_version = '4.12'
ext.constraint_layout_version = '1.0.2'
ext.rxjava_version = '1.1.3'
ext.rxandroid_version = '1.1.0'
ext.mpchart_version = 'v3.0.2'
ext.realm_version = '3.3.2'
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$realm_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

add `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` in `repositories`

And use Android studio 3.0 preview for this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

simply add this into your project level gradle

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'`

it is because you have implementation() method in your app level gradle file

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer tested and works on Android Studio 3.0 Canary 6.

Upgrade gradle version in your project level gradle classpath to a more recent one.

Of what I understand regarding [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html) about gradle / gradle plugin version compatibility it should work with gradle plugin version 2.3.3 and gradle version 3.3 (anybody correct me if I'm wrong):

[image]

Anyway I had to upgrade the plugin to version 3.0.0-alpha6 to get rid of the error. To do so make this change in project level build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6'
```

Note I had a different gradle version than yours in my gradle-wrapper.properties (4.1):

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-milestone-1-all.zip
```

So if you change these both lines in these both files it should works.
Note that `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4` suggested by @Narendra kumawat didn't work for me, I had to use alpha6.